# How to extract all verb list form Get-Command

Tags: command-line, powershell

Of course I know we can use the built-in method to do this,we just run command

`(Get-Verb).Verb`

Then I can get what I want.But I want to know how to extract **all distinct** from the result of `Get-Command`.I should extract the command name firstly like

```
(Get-Command).Name
```

But I don't know how to do the next step..Can anybody tell me something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**: `(Get-Command).Verb | Get-Unique`

**Long Answer**:
Pipe things to Get-Member to see what you are chasing.
You know you wanted something in Get-Command:

```
Get-Command | Get-Member
```

In the results, you can find "Verb" is a property, just like "Name" is.
So far: `(Get-Command).Verb`
You said you wanted distinct, which means you need to pipe that to Get-Unique.

Voila: `(Get-Command).Verb | Get-Unique`